# How can I solve ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException - android

Tags: android

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    Context context;
    private String[] myString;
    private static final Random rgenerator = new Random();
    private AdView adView;
    int index = 0;
    private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-7628432187347131/3277094808";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        // Create an ad.
        adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
        adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);

        context = this;
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ads_lin);
        layout.addView(adView);

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                .addTestDevice("5B895A3CC0CA50D56506E300A4C8342B")
                .addTestDevice("D039292A1F434C999B21503D63D6FD88")

                .addTestDevice("TEST_EMULATOR").build();

        // Start loading the ad in the background.

        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        // Start loading the ad in the background.
        final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quote);

        Resources res = getResources();
        myString = res.getStringArray(R.array.quote);
        final String q = myString[rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length)];
        tv.setText(q);
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        Button btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
        Button btnPreview = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPreview);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                myString = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.quote);
                index = rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length);
                String q = myString[index];
                tv.setText(q);
            }
        });

        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String q = myString[index++];
                tv.setText(q);
            }
        });

        btnPreview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                String q = myString[index--];
                        tv.setText(q);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (adView != null) {
            adView.resume();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        if (adView != null) {
            adView.pause();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

    /** Called before the activity is destroyed. */
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // Destroy the AdView.
        if (adView != null) {
            adView.destroy();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

I don't know how can I solve this error, I am beginner with android development and I don't know how to write the code to solve this problem.
I am looking on internet for an hour but I didn't found something to help me.
Here LOGCAT:

```
09-22 13:05:43.838: E/dalvikvm(26277): adjustAdaptiveCoef max=4194304, min=1048576, ut=568
09-22 13:06:06.510: E/AndroidRuntime(26277): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-22 13:06:06.510: E/AndroidRuntime(26277): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=670; index=-1
09-22 13:06:06.510: E/AndroidRuntime(26277):    at com.example.stiaica.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:80)
09-22 13:06:06.510: E/AndroidRuntime(26277):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4432)
09-22 13:06:06.510: E/AndroidRuntime(26277):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18338)
09-22 13:06:06.510: E/AndroidRuntime(26277):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
09-22 13:06:06.510: E/AndroidRuntime(26277):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-22 13:06:06.510: E/AndroidRuntime(26277):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-22 13:06:06.510: E/AndroidRuntime(26277):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5283)
09-22 13:06:06.510: E/AndroidRuntime(26277):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-22 13:06:06.510: E/AndroidRuntime(26277):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-22 13:06:06.510: E/AndroidRuntime(26277):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
09-22 13:06:06.510: E/AndroidRuntime(26277):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
```

Can somebody help me with the code? Thanks
    09-22 13:06:06.510: E/AndroidRuntime(26277):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you searched, you didn't search enough.

The problem is basically this line: `String q = myString[index--];`

The exception occures if the variable `index` is less than 0. So you try to access an negative value, which doesn't exist, so it throws an exception.

There are a few things you can try:

- Check if the variable `index` is greater than 0
- If it's not greater than 0: Either set it to 0 or you can set it to the last point of the array (for example, if the array has the size 10, you can set it to index 9, so you'd have an continuous loop throughout the whole array
- Or you can simply not go below 0.

First one is for negative and second one for positive:

```
if(index < 0)
{ 
    index = myString.length - 1;
}

if(index >= myString.length)
{ 
    index = 0;
}
```

Comment: What code have I to add, when I go below 0 pass to 670(I have 670 texts in xml file). Thank you

Comment: Quick and dirty: `if(index < 0){ index = myString.length - 1;}`.  And in the opposite direction: `if(index >= myString.length){ index = 0;}`